# Python any() function within a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm new to Python (2 weeks!) and struggling with the following:

I have a list of URLs that I want to iterate through and find just certain URLs. To do this
I want to test any members of a tuple are present in the URL.

I've figured out I need a any() statement but can't get the syntax right:

```
allurls = [<big list of URLs>]

words = ('bob', 'fred', 'tom')

urlsIwant = [x for x in allurls if any(w for w in words) in x]
```

gets me

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool
```

I don't think it's relevant but my actual code is

```
urlsIwant = sorted(set([x for x in allurls if dict['value'] in x and any(w for w in words) in x]))
```

Comment: Indeed it was, worked perfectly. I'm still trying to figger the syntax tho - why is the "in x" within the any() function?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Include the `in x` in the `any()`:

```
urlsIwant = [x for x in allurls if any(w in x for w in words)]
```